# Make multiple copies of the same report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Report to produce PDF formatted reports and I'm calling the rpt file from my system and the system is passing in the input data for the stored procedure which cr is calling. My issue is that I need to make multiple copies of the same report within the same PDf file. Is there any configuration in Crystal Report to duplicate the number of produced reports in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your report as a subreport(s) in another report. The main report will be just a shell. You cannot use this approach if you already have subreports because Crystal reports does not support nested subreports. In this case you need to export each report to a separate PDF and then combine all PDF files in a single file programmatically.  I am not sure what do you mean by "system", something you implemented or developed? If you are using an existing product it is possible that it supports combining multiple PDFs in a single file.